# VC++ Classes. Static variables error unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, class

I have this error that keeps haunting me in all of my programs that is probably just me overlooking something.

code snippet where this error appears:

```
class myClass {
private:
    int x;
public:
    static int getX() {
        x = 10;
        return x;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << myClass::getX() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error I am getting says :

> error unresolved external symbol

What is causeing this or what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Use static getter only for static variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a class you are trying to access the non-static variable using the static method which will not work. You can turn the private member variable `x` into static and initialize it outside the class. Then your example can look like:

```
#include <iostream>
class myClass {
private:
    static int x;
public:
    static int getX()
    {
        x = 10;
        return x;
    }
};
int myClass::x = 0;

int main() {
    std::cout << myClass::getX() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx. I acctualy forgot the static int in the example i made (in my program it was acctualy a static int). but i had forgotten the                                                                 int myClass::x = 0; in my .cpp file (class in my header file) so it still worked!

Answer (score 2):

A `static` member function of class `foo` is not associated with an object of that class (doesn't have the `this` pointer).

And how can you access the member variables of `foo` without an object? Unless they are `static` themselves, you can't.

You must create an instance of `foo` first.

In your case:

```
static int myClass::getX() {
    myClass obj;
    obj.x = 10;
    return obj.x;
}
```

Comment: @sladet In that case the error you are getting doesn't come from the code you've posted. Edit your question with the complete error message. Unresolved external symbol. Which symbol is that?